# Java: Iterate JMenuItem from ArrayList with HashMaps

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jframe, actionlistener

I have a JFrame with a menubar, in which i'd like some dynamic menus, as in, depending on the size of the ArrayList with HashLists. The problem here is that i then got a dynamic amount of JMenuItems, so i need a way to get as much variables as HashLists. In this case i made the name of the variable static, but obviously that's not working on the ActionListener, since all MenuItems will have the same ActionListener.

I'm wondering how to solve this, and how to get a menu with a dynamic amount of menuitems which all have unique actionlisteners.

```
private ArrayList<HashMap> menuLijst;
```

.

```
    for (HashMap h : menuLijst) {
        String vraag = (String) h.get("vraag");
        JMenuItem qMenu = new JMenuItem(vraag);
        informatie.add(qMenu);
        qMenu.addActionListener(this);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do when a menu item is clicked?

Comment: I want an action to occur, for instance, show a table or a diagram in the current frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do in your ActionListener, you can either use `this`, as you do right now and in the actionPerformed you can then use `((JMenutItem)event.getSource())` to see which menu item has been clicked. Alternatively, you could register as many ActionListeners as there are menus, like this:

```
for (final HashMap h : menuLijst) {
    final String vraag = (String) h.get("vraag");
    final JMenuItem qMenu = new JMenuItem(vraag);
    informatie.add(qMenu);
    qMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               // here event.getSource() is the same as qMenu
               System.out.println("Menu "+qMenu+" with label "+vraag+" has been pressed");
               System.out.println("HashMap is "+h);
         }
    });
}
```

But to me (and also seeing your previous questions), it seems that you are abusing the usage of `HashMap` instead of using appropriate new objects. I don't know what else is in your HashMap, let's say that you have 3 keys: "vraag", "answer", "grade", you could create the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
     private String vraag;
     private String answer;
     private int grade;

     // And getters and setters here.
}
```

And have a `List<MyClass>` instead of `List<HashMap>`.

Comment: " And have a List instead of List." ?

Comment: @TimLagerburg Sorry, I forgot to put the backtiks which prevented the typing from showing.

Comment: No problem. Think is gonna be (part of) the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you want to use a HashMap for your Strings. If you save an ArrayList of Strings, and loop over them to add them all to the menu, you can add actionListeners to all of them, just as you are doing now.

In your ActionListener, check which button is clicked by looping through the ArrayList, and comparing to the name of the clicked button.

Comment: That is because there's more data in the hashlist beside that String. That's data i wanted to call on when comparing the actionlistener with the list

Comment: OK, never mind that part then. Still, you can check in the ActionListener which button is clicked by comparing it to the strings in the HashMaps in the ArrayList.

Comment: I found my way around now. Thans for your help.